# Replace all spaces in string inside curly braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I need to replace all spaces in strings inside curly braces (including a prefix).
Example:

From: `x{Test test} test test x{Test test test } test {Test test}`

To    `x{Test_test} test test x{Test_test_test } test {Test test}`

(only applies to `x{}` - when curly braces include x prefix)

I can do it with help of lookhead/lookbehind but this does not work in PHP/PCRE

```
`(?<=x\{[^\{\}]+)\s+(?=[^\{\}]+\})`
```

The problem is how to do it PHP/PCRE compatible with preg_replace function?

Comment: What about space before `}` in `x{Test_test_test }` ?

Comment: The same like in the end: x{ Test test test } => x{ Test_test_test }

Comment: Easier to do with `preg_replace_callback`: `preg_replace_callback('~\bx{[^{}]+}~', function ($m) { return preg_replace('~(?<!{)\s++(?!})~', '_', $m[0]); }, $str)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `\G` bases regex for this:

```
$str = 'x{Test test} test test x{Test test test } test {Test test}';

$repl = preg_replace('/(?:x{|(?<!^)\G)[^\s}]*\K\s+(?!})/', '_', $str);
//=> x{Test_test} test test x{Test_test_test } test {Test test}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kr92ks/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- `(?:x{|(?<!^)\G)`: Matches `x{` or end of previous match
- `\K`: Reset current match info
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace
- `(?!})`: Assert we don't have an `}` immediate ahead